# Running a PropTypes func from another function

Tags: reactjs

Excuse a Reactjs noob.
I have this following markup, which is working fine.

```
...
render() {
  return (
    <UnitsFilter
        onChange={this.props.onFilter}
...
```

The onFilter is defined here as a function:

```
...
App.propTypes = {
  onFilter: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
...
```

And:

```
...
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  onFilter: (id, type) => filterUnits(id, type),
...
```

---

Now, I need to re-arrange, to run two functions on the onChange event, I am wrapping it in `handleChange` as follows:

```
...
handleChange() {
  this.foo();

  const { onFilter } = this.props;
  onFilter();
}

render() {
  return (
    <UnitsFilter
      onChange={this.handleChange}
...
```

The foo function works, but now onFilter is broken. No errors, nothing is happening. What am I doing wrong? Appreciate the help.

Comment: You might need to write mapDispatchToProps like

`const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return { onFilter: (id, type) => dispatch(filterUnits(id, type))}
}` The object syntax might not work because you are writing a new function inside it

Comment: Thank you, I tried this, but it made no difference, same problem (broken, no errors) :-(

Comment: what do you mean by broken, you are not passing `id, type` parameters to `onFilter();` this might be one reason

Comment: Great! I was so close. By passing id and type like so, it now works. `handleChange(id, type) {
        this.foo();

        const { onFilter } = this.props;
        onFilter(id, type);
    }`

Comment: Did you also need to make the change to mapDispatchToProps as I suggested

Comment: How can I upvote this as the correct answer?

Comment: I will post it as an answer shortly

Comment: I did not need to change the dispatch :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the `id` and the `type` attribute to `onFilter` function from your handleChange function. You would probably need to write

```
handleChange(id, type) {
  this.foo();

  const { onFilter } = this.props;
  onFilter(id, type);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you